# VBA How to continue showing arrays elements after nothing

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop, iteration, skip

I have a problem with my excel macro.
I would like to find names in the excel file and copy it to different cells.
I created an array with names and FOR loop to check it. In that for loop i'm looking for names from array. The problem is: If there is no name from array in the cells program stops and give me MsgBox "No name: " + persons(j) and after this program stops. Is is possible to give user information "there is no that name in the file" and skip this iteration ?

Many thanks for help !

Here is my code:

```
Sub wyszukaj()
    Dim persons As Variant
    persons = Array("Dawid", "Mikael", "John", "Alice", "Katerine")
    Dim rowNum As Long
    Dim foundRowNum As String
    Dim findName As String
    Dim j As Long

    For j = LBound(persons) To UBound(persons)
        Dim found As Range
        Dim curSheet As Worksheet
        Dim LastCell As Range
        Dim FirstAddr As String
        With Range("A:A")
            Set LastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
        End With
        Dim nothingInCell As Object
        Set nothingInCell = Nothing

        Set FoundCell = Range("A:A").Find(persons(j), After:=LastCell)

        If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox ("No name: " + persons(j))
        End If

        Debug.Print FoundCell.Value

        If Not FoundCell <> persons(j) Then
            FirstAddr = FoundCell.Address
        End If
        Next j

        Dim counter As Integer
        Dim i As Integer
        counter = 0

        Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
            counter = counter + 1
            Set FoundCell = Range("A:A").FindNext(After:=FoundCell)
            If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddr Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

        foundRowNum = FoundCell.Address
        rowNum = Range(foundRowNum).Row

        For i = rowNum To rowNum + counter - 1
            Cells(i, 1).Copy Cells(i, 8)
            Cells(i, 2).Copy Cells(i, 9)
        Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the following structure:

```
If FoundCell Is Nothing Then 
    'nothing found
Else
    'something found
End If
```

All the part that relies on `FoundCell` needs to be in the `Else` part above.

```
Sub wyszukaj()
    Dim persons As Variant
    persons = Array("Dawid", "Mikael", "John", "Alice", "Katerine")
    Dim rowNum As Long
    Dim foundRowNum As String
    Dim findName As String
    Dim j As Long

    For j = LBound(persons) To UBound(persons)
        Dim found As Range
        Dim curSheet As Worksheet
        Dim LastCell As Range
        Dim FirstAddr As String
        With Range("A:A")
            Set LastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
        End With
        Dim nothingInCell As Object
        Set nothingInCell = Nothing

        Set FoundCell = Range("A:A").Find(persons(j), After:=LastCell)

        If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            'nothing found
            MsgBox ("No name: " + persons(j))
        Else
            'something found
            Debug.Print FoundCell.Value
    
            If Not FoundCell <> persons(j) Then
                FirstAddr = FoundCell.Address
            End If
        End If
    Next j

    Dim counter As Long
    Dim i As Long
    counter = 0

    Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
        counter = counter + 1
        Set FoundCell = Range("A:A").FindNext(After:=FoundCell)
        If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddr Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    foundRowNum = FoundCell.Address
    rowNum = Range(foundRowNum).Row

    For i = rowNum To rowNum + counter - 1
        Cells(i, 1).Copy Cells(i, 8)
        Cells(i, 2).Copy Cells(i, 9)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: OMG so simple ... Thanks a lot !